# How to prove that if $\mu$ is finite, then it is sum-finite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Im having some trouble with how to prove that if $\mu$ is finite then it is sum-finite.

I know that if $\mu$ is finite on a measurable space (E,A) if $\mu<\infty$ and that $\mu$ is sum-finite on a measurable space (E,A) if $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n$, where $\mu_n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is finite measures.
But I dont know how to tie these definitions together.

Comment: By "sum-finite", do you mean $\sigma-$finite ? If so, are you sure of your definition ?...

Comment: Your definition is incomplete. What is $\mu_n$?

Comment: No I mean sum :))

Comment: note that in the definition of sum-finite, the $\mu_n$ measures are finite. Can you find a sequence of finite measures on (E,A), whose sum is $\mu$?

Comment: dont forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, choose your favorite positive sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that sum to 1, and let $\mu_n=a_n \mu$ simply be a scaled version of $\mu$. Then for all elements $B$ of the $\sigma$-algebra $A$ we find:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n(B) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \mu(B)=\mu(B)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\mu(B).$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: The trivial measure $\zeta$ that assigns 0 measure to all sets is finite.

Solution:

> $$ \mu = \mu + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\zeta $$ is an expression for $\mu$ as a countable sum of finite measures.

Comment: Why the downvote?